# Python: Read a file until a line matches a string in binary mode

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, so i have seen the other questions but i run into a unique issue. I have to open the file in binary mode in order to read it (i don't really understand why, but it works). and I can easily print out the lines of the file no problem. But when I try to find a specific line using `re.search`, I have issues because I have a string pattern and byte objects. Here is what I have so far:

```
input_file = open(input_file_path,  'rb',  0)

for line in input_file:
    if re.search("enum " + enum_name,  line, 0):
        print("Found it")
        print(line)
        exit()
```

enum_name is a user input so I really need to know how I can use both a string and the variable in my search of a file opened in binary mode (or how to open this file not in binary mode, I get the can't have unbuffered text I/O error when not in binary mode). I have tried making my pattern for the search binary but I don't know what to do with the variable when I do that.

Comment: A better question might be why can't you open the file in text mode

Comment: Tagged with `python-3.x` since you mentioned a bytes object.

Comment: In windows, it's different to read a file in binary or not (if not, windows line endings are replaced by \n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a byte string as the pattern in your regex, something like the following should work:

```
if re.search(b"enum " + enum_name.encode('utf-8'), line):
    ...
```

The `enum_name.encode('utf-8')` here is used to convert the user input to a `bytes` object, depending on your environment you may need to use a difference encoding.

Note that if your regex is really this simple, then you can probably just use a substring search instead.

Comment: This!!! I saw something like this earlier today but i couldn't find it again when i ran into the problem. This worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need re. Try

```
if "enum " + enum_name in line:
```

Reading with 'b' is mostly about line endings.

Comment: Based on the context of the question, I'm pretty sure OP is using Python 3.x, which means there are more significant differences when reading in binary mode.